# How to remove the bottom table headers (column names) in WP_List_Table?

Tags: wp-list-table

By default, the `WP_List_Table` has column names at the top and the bottom of the table.

How can I remove the bottom table headers? Thanks.

p.s. I have already subclassed the `WP_List_Table`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can override the [`WP_List_Table::display()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_list_table/display/) method and remove the `tfoot` which contains the bottom table headers:

```php
<tfoot>
<tr>
    <?php $this->print_column_headers( false ); ?>
</tr>
</tfoot>
```

Or you can add a specific `class` to the relevant admin page and use CSS to *visually* hide the bottom table headers:

```css
.my-plugin-foo-page table.wp-list-table > tfoot {
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: Yes, I'm using `display()` override. it's not future-proof, though.

Comment: Yes, I agree. So if you are just concerned about the display, then the CSS approach would be a better option.

Comment: but this will raise another issue, Flash of Unstyled Content (FOUC), as CSS may be loaded slower than the layout display.

Comment: And I agreed, but I've no further comments regarding the FOUC.. however, if you want, you can suggest to the WP core about something like a filter which lets one decide whether the `tfoot` should be displayed or not.

Comment: thanks for your suggestion.